# gdb python API dynamic cast not work as expected

Tags: python, c++, gdb

The document in this [link](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Values-From-Inferior.html#Values-From-Inferior) says that `Value.dynamic_cast` works like dynamic cast in C++, but in the following experiement, it shows that the `Value.cast` works like dynamic cast in C++, and `Value.dynamic_cast` gives some value I don't understand.

This is the sample code

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual void p() {}
  int i =3;
};
class Base2 {
public:
  virtual void f() {}
  int i2 =4;
};
class Derived: public Base, public Base2{
  public:
  void p() override{}
  int t =4;
};
int main() {
   auto* p = new Derived();
   Base2* pb2 = p;
   Base* pb = p;
   return 0;
}
```

Run the code, and print the values of `p`, `pb`, and `pb2`

```
(gdb) p p
$1 = (Derived *) 0x613c20
(gdb) p pb // 
$2 = (Base *) 0x613c20
(gdb) p pb2
$3 = (Base2 *) 0x613c30
```

Then use python script to print the value as follows,
the `Value.dynamic_cast` will give

```
(gdb) py print(ppb2.dynamic_cast(ppb2.dynamic_type))
0x400808 <vtable for Derived+16>
```

And the `Value.cast` gives the correct derived pointer,

```
(gdb) py print(ppb2.cast(ppb2.dynamic_type))
0x613c20
```

`pp`, `ppb`, and `ppb2` are the corresponding values but in Python env, got from the following code.

```
(gdb) py pp = gdb.parse_and_eval('p')
(gdb) py print(pp)
0x613c20
(gdb) py ppb2 = gdb.parse_and_eval('pb2')
(gdb) py print(ppb2)
0x613c30
(gdb) py print(ppb2.cast(ppb2.dynamic_type))
0x613c20
(gdb) py print(ppb2.dynamic_cast(ppb2.dynamic_type))
0x400808 <vtable for Derived+16>
```

Why `Value.dynamic_cast` will give `0x400808 <vtable for Derived+16>` instead of `0x613c20` (the derived pointer)?

Comment: That looks like a gdb bug that should be reported.

Comment: @ssbssa Thanks~ I will leave this question open for a period. And if there is answer to it, I will report this bug to the gdb.